# Ошибка float на Android Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, float

Проблема в том что на ПК все работает хорошо, а вот на Android float почему то отбрасывает левую часть, вот код

```
    Dictionary<string, float> data = Assembling.buildings[id].dataUp;
    float value = 0;
    Debug.Log("PT__ " + data["productionTime"]);
    value = data["productionTime"] / (lvl * 0.4f);
    Debug.Log("PT1__ " + value);
```

[image: результат работы скрипта]

результат работы на ПК указан зелеными стрелками на фото а красными на андроид.
Что же не так? Может кто помочь с данным вопросом. Поиск перекопал но пока не нашел и вот почти впервые в жизни задаю сам вопрос.
Спасибо!

Comment: может  ты  гдето на  100 умножаешь  для   андроида  ??

Comment: ты  ж  видишь  что   там   ровно  в  сто  раз  больше    значения

Comment: мне  кажется  чтото   умножается  в  этой  конструкции  Assembling.buildings[id].dataUp

Comment: Нет не умножал, ответ уже дали. Спасибо и вам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно причина в **преобразовании типа**. У Вас на компьютере **32,5** - дробный тип данных, а Android ставит "." может быть в этом проблема. Либо используйте тот символ разделителя целой и дробной части, который принят в вашей стране (для России это запятая).
Вот [ссылка](http://i-const-t.blogspot.com/2011/03/net-c.html) может поможет

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! Выбрал 3 вариант из ссылки.

Comment: Не за что обращайтесь!